# How to interpret RS232C interface communication written using Pascal to C#

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, pascal

I've a sample pascal program, provided in a technical handbook of coin counter S350/360 machine, that enables communication between the machine and a computer using RS232C cable. I've came up with the following equivalent C# code and for some reason only the procedures that only need to write data to the serial port are executing and working successfully. I can only write data to the port but cannot read any data from it. I checked this using a Serial Sniffer and it turns out it only sniffs data written to the port, using the C# program, but cannot read any data back. Could you guys help me with what's going on here?

First here is the original Pascal code of the sample program.

```
uses crt;

const
{ COM1: RS232 port address }
RXTX = $3F8; { $2F8 if COM2: is used }
ACK = 6;
NAK = 21;
ESC = 27;

var
dummy,
checkSum : integer;
key : char;
protocol : integer;

procedure InitComm;
{ Set baudrate to 9600, 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit }
var i : integer;
begin
i := 1843200 div 9600 div 16;
port[RXTX + 3] := $80;
port[RXTX + 1] := hi(i);
port[RXTX]:= lo(i);
port[RXTX + 3] := 3;
port[RXTX + 4] := $A;
while odd(port[RXTX + 5]) do
begin
dummy := port[RXTX];
delay(10);
end;
end; { InitComm }

procedure Tx(data : integer);
{ Transmit a character on serial channel }
begin
while port[RXTX + 5] and $20 = 0 do;
port[RXTX] := data and $FF;
end; { Tx }

function RxWait : integer;
{ Waits for a character from serial channel }
begin
while not odd(port[RXTX + 5]) do;
RxWait := port[RXTX];
end; { RxWait }

procedure Tx2(data : integer);
{ Transmit a char on serial channel + Calculate check sum }
begin
Tx(data);
checkSum := (checkSum + data) and $FF;
end; { Tx2 }

procedure TxCommand(c1, c2 : char;
sendCheckSum : boolean);
{ Transmit command (no data) on serial channel }
begin
Tx(ESC);
checkSum := 0;
Tx2(ord(c1));
Tx2(ord(c2));
if sendCheckSum then
begin
Tx2(checkSum);
dummy := RxWait;
end;
end; { TxCommand }

function ReadNumber(n : integer) : real;
{ Read n bytes from serial channel }
var
number: real;
i : integer;
begin
number := 0;
checkSum := 0;
for i := 1 to n do
number := number * 256 + RxWait;
dummy := RxWait;
ReadNumber := number;
end; { ReadNumber }

procedure Revisions;
var
tmp : integer;
sw,
prot : real;
begin
TxCommand('P', 'R', FALSE);
checkSum := 0;
tmp := RxWait;
sw := tmp + RxWait / 100.0;
protocol := RxWait;
prot := protocol + RxWait / 100.0;
dummy := RxWait;
tmp := RxWait;
writeln('Software revision: ', sw:4:2);
writeln('Protocol revision: ', prot:4:2);
end; { Revisions }

procedure ReadCountReg;
begin
TxCommand('R', 'C', FALSE);
writeln(ReadNumber(4):11:0, ' coins counted.');
dummy := RxWait;
end; { ReadCountReg }

procedure ReadAccReg;
begin
TxCommand('R', 'A', FALSE);
writeln(ReadNumber(4):11:0, ' coins in accumulator.');
dummy := RxWait;
end; { ReadAccReg }

procedure Setbatch(limit : longint);
begin
TxCommand('W', 'L', FALSE);
case protocol of
1 : begin
Tx2(limit div 256);
Tx2(limit mod 256);
end;
2 : begin
Tx2( limit div 16777216);
Tx2((limit div 65536) mod 256);
Tx2((limit div 256) mod 256);
Tx2( limit mod 256);
end;
end; { case protocol }
Tx2(checkSum);
dummy := RxWait;
end; { Setbatch }
```

In the protocol descriptions two logical operators are used,
+ for arithmetic addition and ^ for logical AND.
All messages have the following principal structure:

```
Computer SC 350/360
–––––––> ESC (message start)
–––––––> Command
<––––––> Data (direction depends on command)
<––––––> Check sum (direction depends on command)
<––––––– Receipt:
        - ACK (if check sum is correct) or
        - NAK (if check sum is incorrect)
```

If the data is a binary number, the most significant byte (character) is
sent first. If the data is a text string, the first character of the string is
sent first. A text string always ends with a NULL character.

The check sum for received characters in a message is derived as
follows:
The addition of every hexadecimal character value, except those for
the message start (ESC), forms the sum. The check sum is then the
sum ^255.
If any of the fault conditions listed below occurs, the computer
should wait for at least 250 ms from the time that the last character
was received before re-sending the message:

- The computer receives an incorrect check sum.
- The machine has sent NAK.
- The machine sends “invalid data”.
- The machine does not respond within 250 ms.
  The machine accepts all messages when counting except the message
  that sets a new batch quantity.

For example; To start the machine 'TxCommand('M', '1', TRUE);' is issued as written in the handbook; I've implemented the pascal code for this in C#.Net and have successfully issued this command and the machine started right away. What I couldn't get working was the procedures 'ReadCountReg', 'ReadCountReg'and 'Setbatch'.

Below is the C# code I implemented:

```
 public class CoinCounter : IDisposable
{

    private const int RXTX = 0x3F8;
    private const int ACK = 6;
    private const int NAK = 21;
    private const int ESC = 27;

    private int dummy, checkSum;
    private char key;
    private int protocol;

    public SerialPort port;
    private bool _disposed = false;
    public CoinCounter()
    {
        //Initialize Communication
        port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        port.Open();
        port.DtrEnable = true;
        port.RtsEnable = true;

    }

    public void ClosePort()
    {
        if (port.IsOpen)
            port.Close();
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                DisposeManagedResources();
            }
            DisposeUnmanagedResources();
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    private  void DisposeManagedResources() 
    {
        port.Dispose();
    }
    private  void DisposeUnmanagedResources() { }

     ~CoinCounter() 
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Tx(int data)
    {

        port.Write(new byte[] { (byte)(data & 0xFF) }, 0, 1);

    }

    public int RxWait()
    {

        int readByte = 0;
        CommTimer timer = new CommTimer();
        timer.Start(250);
        while ((port.BytesToRead == 0) && (timer.timedout == false))
        {
        }
        if (port.BytesToRead > 0)
            readByte = port.ReadByte();

        return readByte;

    }

    public void Tx2(int data)
    {
        Tx(data);
        checkSum = (checkSum + data) & 0xFF;
    }

    public void TxCommand(char c1, char c2, bool sendCheckSum)
    {
        Tx(ESC);
        checkSum = 0;
        Tx2((int)c1);
        Tx2((int)c2);
        if (sendCheckSum)
        {
            Tx2(checkSum);
            dummy = RxWait();
        }
    }

    public double ReadNumber(int n)
    {
        double number;
        int i;
        number = checkSum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            number = number * 256 + RxWait();
        dummy = RxWait();
        return number;
    }

    public void Revisions(out double softVersion, out double protocolVersion)
    {
        int tmp;
        TxCommand('P', 'R', false);
        checkSum = 0;
        tmp = RxWait();
        softVersion = tmp + RxWait() / 100.0;
        protocol = RxWait();
        protocolVersion = protocol + RxWait() / 100.0;
        dummy = RxWait();
        tmp = RxWait();
    }

    public double ReadCountReg()
    {
        TxCommand('R', 'C', false);
        double coinsCounted = ReadNumber(4);
        dummy = RxWait();
        return coinsCounted;
    }

    public double ReadAccReg()
    {
        TxCommand('R', 'A', false);
        double coinsInAccumulator = ReadNumber(4);
        dummy = RxWait();
        return coinsInAccumulator;
    }

    public void SetBatch(long limit)
    {
        TxCommand('W', 'L', false);
        switch (protocol)
        {
            case 1:
                Tx2((int)(limit / 256));
                break;
            case 2:
                Tx2((int)(limit / 16777216));
                Tx2((int)(limit / 65536) % 256);
                Tx2((int)(limit / 256) % 256);
                Tx2((int)(limit % 256));
                break;
        }
        Tx2(checkSum);
        dummy = RxWait();
    }

    public class CommTimer
    {
        public System.Timers.Timer tmrComm = new System.Timers.Timer();
        public bool timedout = false;
        public CommTimer()
        {
            timedout = false;
            tmrComm.AutoReset = false;
            tmrComm.Enabled = false;
            tmrComm.Interval = 1000; //default to 1 second
            tmrComm.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedCommEvent);
        }

        public void OnTimedCommEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            timedout = true;
            tmrComm.Stop();
        }

        public void Start(double timeoutperiod)
        {
            tmrComm.Interval = timeoutperiod; 
            tmrComm.Stop();
            timedout = false;
            tmrComm.Start();
        }


    }


}
```

Note that the hand book states:
1.  For simplicity the handshake lines are not used in this example.
2.  No check sum implemented.

While most of the commands, with simple checksum calculation, can successfully communicate with the machine I couldn't get, for example, 'ReadCountReg' procedure to work and see the results of counted coins. The protocol for this procedure is;

```
Computer SC 350/360
–––––––> ESC
–––––––> “R”
–––––––> “C”
<––––––– CountRegister (CR)
<––––––– (CR ^ FF00,000016 + CR ^ FF,000016 + CR ^ FF0016 +CR ^ FF16) ^ FF16
<––––––– ACK
```

Could you guys help me get this working as I don't have much experience with the serial port communication and could help me resolve my issue.

Comment: I don't really follow what you're asking. 'What have I left out?' is a bit vague.

Comment: @MikeW I meant help me see the problem with the equivalent C# code i came up with

Comment: In `RxWait` you are polling in a very tight loop. Try putting e.g. a `Thread.Sleep(50)` in the `while` loop.

Comment: @Henrik What do you mean a very tight loop? Am I making it wait longer using the timer? (250ms)? By the way my old code used 'Thread.Sleep(100)' and then only 'port.ReadByte' is called after it. But nothing was being read

Comment: This `while (port.BytesToRead == 0) ;` keeps 1 CPU 100% busy. Change it to `while (port.BytesToRead == 0) Thread.Sleep(50);` to only check for input every 50ms.

Comment: I don't understand. But I am using timer to break out of the loop on time out which is when 250ms is reached. Are you suggesting `while(port.BytesToRead==0 && timer.timeout==false){Thread.Sleep(50)}'?

Comment: Yes, I just shortened it a bit to fit in a comment. Probably a bad idea.

Comment: @Henrik okay I will do that. But do u think that will resolve the problem of no data being sent back from the port?

Comment: I didn't know abut the `SerialPort` class in .net. For who is interested, the documentation and some sample code can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

`SerialPort` implements `IDisposable`.  You are acquiring a serial port and you are never disposing it - this is an error.  If your usage model is one wherein the client code will always make a call to you when it's done, you should Dispose the object then (this doesn't look like your model).  Otherwise, [you should implement IDisposable yourself](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/stevehawley/archive/2006/09/21/10887.aspx) (follow the code template. In your case, you will be implementing DisposeManagedResources() and disposing the serial port then) and ensure that your object is Disposed when finished.

A final option is to have the calling code allocate and dispose the serial port and pass it in to the constructor of your code.

Comment: My client code calls the 'ClosePort' Method, which is found in the above class, upon exiting the program. Should I implement disposing the serial port even when I am closing it?

Comment: If an object implements IDisposable, you MUST dispose it.  There is no guarantee that Close does that for you.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. I've now implemented IDisposable in my 'CoinCounter' class and disposed the serial port in the DisposeManagedResources() Method. I don't know if this was the reason bytes were not being read when calling 'ReadCountReg' method in the sample program but I'll try it out tomorrow when I will get to test the code by connecting my PC to the coin counter machine

Comment: I just executed the code connecting my PC to the machine and it still is not getting bytes to read from the 'ReadCountReg' method.Perhaps could you see the original pascal code and the equivalent C# code i came up with and If my implementation was wrong? thanks

Comment: I've edited my question with the IDisposable implementation. There seems to be no data being read from the serial port while it can write data to the port. I used serial sniffer to check that and I don't know why data is not being read. Could you help me please?