# How to run Turbo Pascal code that uses MS-DOS Graphics Mode on Windows 10?

Tags: graphics, virtualbox, mouse, dosbox, turbo-pascal

I've found some old code that I've written in Turbo Pascal and that I would like to run. I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask.

I've installed Turbo Pascal with DOSBox from sourceforge (installed it on Windows 10 in Virtual Box) but the code doesn't run. It opens the window and closes immediately.

The code uses this function:

```pascal
Uses crt, graph;

Procedure Grafika (sterownik,tryb:integer;
                  autodetect:boolean;Path:String);
begin
   if autodetect then
       sterownik:=detect;
   InitGraph(sterownik,tryb,Path);
end;
```

and runs like this:

```pascal
Grafika(1,1,True,'');
```

The code also uses some assembly to handle the cursor, by using interrupt 33h. This is an example function (of a few):

```pascal
Procedure VisibleCur(a: boolean);
Begin
  if a then
    asm
      mov ax, 0001h
      int 33h
    end
  else
    asm
      mov ax, 0002h
      int 33h
    end;
end;
```

Is there a way to run this code somehow? I would really want to see the app, because it was one of the first applications that I've written that is GUI under MS-DOS.

Comment: in DosBox it should run ... IIRC the int 33h is muse (so you should install mouse driver if not present)  DosBox is emulating VGA so even direct I/O access should work if your program end it might be a different cause why not debug your code? excuting your code line per line and see when it crashes and why (IIRC F8 key in TP IDE). Also Turbo CRT has [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21647352/2521214) that it does not work properly on fast CPUs (but that should not be a problem on DosBox unless you overclock it) there are fixed CRT versions out there even exe pathers

Comment: You could also port your code to modern Delphi and run directly on Windows ... you just throw out your BIOS interrupt based stuff and use native events ... and instead of VGA use [Graphics::TBitmap from VCL with direct Pixel Access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699076/2521214)... **Also I just saw `InitGraph` which suggest you use BGI I think you need to change the calling parameters** and also make sure you have propper BGI driver installed/accessible nearby your EXE ... which is most likely the cause of the crash. In case you want to port your code you will need BGI emulator

Comment: @Spektre thanks for the tips. I will try that out. But I don't want to port the code to Delphi The whole idea is to see how the code works in MS DOS. I don't need to port the code. I have code that draws buttons in MSDos and I want to see what those buttons look like. I don't need a GUI app.

Answer (score 1):

Your current setup presents a significant amount of emulation indirection:

> host **>** Windows 10 **>** Virtual Box **>** DOSBox.

I would try to run the app in something more 'baremetal', first just to discard every possible emulation issue. I think DOSBox is available native in most common OSes (Linux, Windows, Apple ...).

Ideal would be to launch from MS-DOS on a real machine. But maybe you can try using a pcem or 86box VM which is more precise in hardware emulation than DOSBox.

Comment: Thanks, I was installing DOSBox on Windows in VirtualBox because I didn't know I could run it on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that to run the code I need to add a path to the BGI, it's not detected automatically. In my case, it was:

```pascal
Grafika(1,1,True,'C:\\TPWDB\\BGI');
```